# Change Default Date to firstday of previous month

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I am trying to change the default date as first day of previous month in  Yii cjuidatepicker.
Date is displaying in the textfield correctly,but in the datepicker popup it shows the current date.

**Code**

```
 $model_form->suspended_date_from =date("d-M-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, 1, date("Y")));
   $date= date('dd-MM-yy', strtotime($model_form->suspended_date_from));
                       $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                            'model' => $model_form,
                            'attribute' => 'suspended_date_from',
                            'htmlOptions' => array(
                                'class' => 'reporttext-field fromdate',
                                'id' => uniqid(),
                            ),
                            'options' => array(

                                'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yy',
                               'defaultDate'=> $date,
                                // 'beforeShowDay'=>'unavailable',


                                'showAnim' => 'fade',
                                //'onSelect' => 'js:function( selectedDate ) {$( ".todate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );}'
                            ),
                        ));
```

How can i show it on the datepicker popup??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorect date format. dd-MM-yy (??) This one return something like 1818-AprApr-1313; so I think it is incorect. If You change date format to d-M-y then You will have what You want.
Whay do you use two different date format ? `("d-M-Y" and "d-M-y")`

```
$date= date('d-M-y', strtotime($model_form->suspended_date_from));
                       $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                            'model' => $model_form,
                            'attribute' => 'suspended_date_from',
                            'htmlOptions' => array(
                                'class' => 'reporttext-field fromdate',
                                'id' => uniqid(),
                            ),
                            'options' => array(

                                'dateFormat' => 'd-M-y',
                               'defaultDate'=> $date,
                                // 'beforeShowDay'=>'unavailable',


                                'showAnim' => 'fade',
                                //'onSelect' => 'js:function( selectedDate ) {$( ".todate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );}'
                            ),
                        ));
```

Something like that works for me.